# Double Array / Unique Random Numbers (Card deck)

Tags: java, eclipse

I am creating a program that has a double array list of a deck of cards. There are two "hands" that will be dealt from this ONE deck. 5 unique cards must be dealt to "comHand" which is a double array which stores the 5 cards. the first [] stores which iteration of the cards being dealt (1st card, 2nd card, etc) and the second [] stores the suit of the card in [0] and the number of the card in [1].

I simplified my code to make sure I get 3 unique draws. There is only one suit and 3 possible numbers to choose from. My code works fine above the /// (the two numbers are always unique). However the code below doesn't yield a unique number sometimes. Can I get some help discerning why this is?

```
        int comHand [][] = new int [5][2];
        card1 = (int) (Math.random()*1);
        card2 = (int) (Math.random()*3);

        comHand[0][0] = card1;
        comHand[0][1] = card2;

        card1 = (int) (Math.random()*1);
        card2 = (int) (Math.random()*3);

        while (card1 == comHand[0][0] && card2 == comHand[0][1]){
            card1 = (int) (Math.random()*1);
            card2 = (int) (Math.random()*3);}

        comHand[1][0] = card1;
        comHand[1][1] = card2;

        ///

        card1 = (int) (Math.random()*1);
        card2 = (int) (Math.random()*3);

        while (card1 == comHand[0][0] && card2 == comHand[0][1]){
            card1 = (int) (Math.random()*1);
            card2 = (int) (Math.random()*3);}
        while (card1 == comHand[1][0] && card2 == comHand[1][1]){
            card1 = (int) (Math.random()*1);
            card2 = (int) (Math.random()*3);}

        comHand[2][0] = card1;
        comHand[2][1] = card2;
```

Comment: Why is this tagged "Javascript"?

Comment: @Bergi Great question, wish I read your comment before I worked out a whole javascript solution.

Comment: (int) (Math.random()*1) will always return 0, and (int) (Math.random()*3) will always return 0, 1 or 2. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 1):

```
    int comHand [][] = new int [5][2];
    ArrayList<Integer> cards = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int totalCards = 52; //Cards in a pack
    for(int x = 1; x <= totalCards; x++)
    {
        cards.add(x);
    }
    //Repeat for 5 cards
    for(int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
    {
        int selectCard = (int)(Math.random()*cards.size()-1);
        comHand[y][0] = cards.get(selectCard) % 13; //13 cards per suit
        comHand[y][1] = cards.get(selectCard) / 13;
        cards.remove(selectCard);
    }
```

Hopefully this is what you were after.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. I am under the impression that && means both conditions must be true and || means only one must be true.

Comment: yes but the way you have set it up it will equal false when one value is unique.

Comment: That's the idea. I want unique card draws. Both values don't need to be different, I can have the same number of different suits.

Comment: I have another way of achieving this. Create a list of possible number including the suits. eg. 1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3... ect then generate a random number with the max value being the length of the list. The selected card is the value at that index. Then remove that value from the list and random again for the next card with the list size as max.

Comment: Sorry that wont work exactly ill write up some code that will like this now

Comment: EDIT: added the modulus to find the suit from the number set

Answer (score 1):

Your while loops seem to have a wrong condition. Try || instead of &&:

```
 while (card1 == comHand[0][0] || card2 == comHand[0][1]) {
            card1 = (int) (Math.random()*1);
            card2 = (int) (Math.random()*3);
 }
```

I'd try another approach since "repeat Math.random() until everything works" is not a good algorithm. It's hard to predict how many steps the algorithm will need to finish (and whether it will always finish).

Use objects for cards instead of int arrays. Pick the cards from a collection using Math.random (or Random) and remove the selected card from that collection. That way it won't get selected again. Or build a deck, shuffle it and just pop top cards from the deck until done. That's very easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot be sure by Using a random in getting a unique in consecutive draws.
Maintain an array, storing the draws of one transaction, and if you get any draw which is present in the array, continue generating a new Random number

Comment: I am aware of this... The code I wrote above is attempting to check the array to see if there is a duplicate card present.